# Running a python script at a random hour CentOS

Tags: python, ubuntu

I've had a good browse through and I can't seem to find an answer covering this anywhere.

Does anyone know how i'd go about running a python script once per day at a random hour between between 9am - 8pm ?

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a [cron job](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to run this every day:

```
sleep $(((RANDOM % 12) * 60)) && /path/to/your/script.py
```

`12` is the number of possible hours to fire off (9AM-8PM inclusive). `$RANDOM` is a system variable that gives you a random value. `sleep` takes in a number of seconds to sleep. The notation `$((...))` calculates the inside expression. When this is used environment variables don't have to be referenced like `$RANDOM`, hence why `$` is left off.

edit: Try running this a few times to see what's happening:

```
echo $RANDOM
```

When this random value is modulo-ed (`x % y`), it will give you a random value between [0,y). In this case you'll get a random number from 0, up to and including 11.

Comment: Ahh gotcha so i'd literally do crontab -e and then add that to the file? My crontab has a "mailto=" so I take it i'd literally add that after it?

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to with `mailto=` but if you run `crontab -e` it should open up your editor where you would add `0 9 * * * <command above>`.

Comment: Ahh I get it so add an entry that does?:
0 0 * * * sleep $(((RANDOM % 12) * 60)) && /path/to/your/script.py

Comment: The second value has to be 9 so it runs at 9AM.

Comment: Hrm when that runs I get 
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: 0 9 * * * sleep $(((RANDOM % 12) * 60)) && /user/scripts/pheme.py is the contrab entry